# matrix entries also matrices in python

Tags: python, numpy

is there a way to create a matrix whose entries are also matrices in Python? I don't see any way to do so with numpy.

*In other words, I want A[i,j] to be a matrix as well.

Comment: Well, you can create 4 dimensional arrays, then the entries for `A[i,j]` would be matrices. But A itself would be a 4 dimensional array (not a matrix) . Is that what you want?

Comment: Matrix should always be 2-dimensional. But you might want to check if you can do it using ndarray.

Comment: Do you specifically want `np.matrix`, or will a `np.array` be ok?  An array can be 3d, 4d, etc, a matrix is always 2d.

Answer (score 3):

If a 4d array is ok, then

```
x = np.zeros((3,4,2,2), dtype=int)
```

where

```
x[0,0].shape # (2,2)
```

If it must be `np.matrix` type, then it has to be 2d.  It can be `dtype=object`, where each element is in turn a 2d matrix.  That construction is a bit more convoluted (a lot more?).

Make an empty array with dtype=object

```
In [565]: x=np.zeros((2,2),dtype=object)

In [566]: x
Out[566]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 0]], dtype=object)
```

Fill each element with a matrix:

```
In [567]: x[0,0]=np.matrix([[0,1],[2,3]])
In [569]: x[0,1]=np.matrix([[0,1],[2,3]])
In [570]: x[1,0]=np.matrix([[0,1],[2,3]])
In [571]: x[1,1]=np.matrix([[0,1],[2,3]])

In [572]: x
Out[572]: 
array([[matrix([[0, 1],
        [2, 3]]), matrix([[0, 1],
        [2, 3]])],
       [matrix([[0, 1],
        [2, 3]]), matrix([[0, 1],
        [2, 3]])]], dtype=object)
```

Turn it into a `matrix`:

```
In [573]: xm=np.matrix(x)

In [574]: xm
Out[574]: 
matrix([[matrix([[0, 1],
         [2, 3]]), matrix([[0, 1],
         [2, 3]])],
        [matrix([[0, 1],
         [2, 3]]), matrix([[0, 1],
         [2, 3]])]], dtype=object)
```

I don't know whether `xm` has any useful computational properties.